# Integration with substitution or parts?

Tags: calculus

How does one find: $$\int^{1}_{0}\frac{x}{(1+x)^4}dx$$ Do we start with a substitution, or apply parts straight away?

Comment: Each will work.

Comment: The substitution $u=1+x$, $du=dx$?

Comment: @Stack Yes, that'll do things way easier.

Comment: Yes, that works fine. You end up integrating $\frac{u-1}{u^4}$, that is, $\frac{1}{u^3}-\frac{1}{u^4}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**
$$\dfrac{x}{(1+x)^4} = \dfrac1{(1+x)^3} - \dfrac1{(1+x)^4}$$